# Is it possible to provide default settings for a service in a module (Angular 2+)

Tags: angular

In Angular 2+ is it possible to configure a service before it is injected into your component. For Example, can one provide default settings for a service in a module at the providers array?

I am writing the service, but I would like to avoid having a `configure()` method and just provide said details at design time.

*I have done some searching but I may not have the correct terminology for my search as I am coming up with no answers.*

Many Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to configure? Please, be clear with your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your service config class and then add its factory to providers in module:

```
providers:
..., {
  provide: ServiceConfig,
  useFactory: serviceConfigFactory,
  deps: [Foo, Bar]
}, ...
...
export function serviceConfigFactory(foo: Foo, bar: Bar): ServiceConfig {
  ...  // build config here
}
```

where Foo and Bar -- your factory function injectable argument classes.

Then inject service config to your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  constructor (private serviceConfig: ServiceConfig)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I get down-voted by someone for not being clear, yet you can answer my question in under 10 minutes.  Thank you for that.

Comment: @Eddie For what it is worth, I didn't down-vote. I was just hoping to get some more details. This is a good answer.

Comment: To add to this answer, the main thing I have been looking for is Factory Provider: https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider